# How to add custom user model in admin panel?

Tags: django

I created a custom user model extending AbstractBaseUser class. code is below.

```
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    sys_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=False, blank=False)    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=127, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)  
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=user_type_choices, null=False, blank=True, help_text="Admin(1)/Institute(2)/Student(3)")  
    access_valid_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    access_valid_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_when = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True )
    created_by = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated_when = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated_by = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # this field is required to login super user from admin panel
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # this field is required to login super user from admin panel
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS must contain all required fields on your User model, 
    # but should not contain the USERNAME_FIELD or password as these fields will always be prompted for.
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'mobile', 'user_type']

    class Meta:
        app_label = "accounts"
        db_table = "users"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    # this methods are require to login super user from admin panel
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    # this methods are require to login super user from admin panel
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser
```

Now in my admin panel only 'groups' is available. I want my custom user mode i.e. UserModel to appear in admin panel so that I can add, edit and delete user from admin user interface.
I tried multiple codes from SO, simplest of them is below

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from accounts.models import UserModel
from django.contrib import admin


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = UserModel

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('mobile',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(UserModel, MyUserAdmin)
```

now I am getting this errors ..
ERRORS:

```
<class 'accounts.admin.MyUserAdmin'>: (admin.E019) The value of 'filter_horizontal[0]' refers to 'groups', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.UserModel'.
<class 'accounts.admin.MyUserAdmin'>: (admin.E019) The value of 'filter_horizontal[1]' refers to 'user_permissions', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.UserModel'.
<class 'accounts.admin.MyUserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.UserModel'.
<class 'accounts.admin.MyUserAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'username', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'MyUserAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'accounts.UserModel'.
<class 'accounts.admin.MyUserAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'first_name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'MyUserAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'accounts.UserModel'.
<class 'accounts.admin.MyUserAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[3]' refers to 'last_name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'MyUserAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'accounts.UserModel'.
<class 'accounts.admin.MyUserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[3]' refers to 'groups', which does not refer to a Field.
```

Please let me know how can I add custom user model successfully to admin UI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin)

> If your custom user model extends django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser, you can use Django’s existing django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin class. **However, if your user model extends AbstractBaseUser, you’ll need to define a custom ModelAdmin class**. It may be possible to subclass the default django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin; **however, you’ll need to override any of the definitions that refer to fields on django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser that aren’t on your custom user class**.

So basically, if you create a new user model from the `AbstractBaseUser` instead of `AbstractUser` you need to create your own custom `ModelAdmin` class, alternatively if you inherit from `UserAdmin` (which is what you're currently doing) you need to override and handle any differences.

Answer (score 7):

@Anurag Rana your custom `UserAdmin`class should look like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from accounts.models import UserModel
from django.contrib import admin


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = UserModel
    list_display = ()  # Contain only fields in your `custom-user-model`
    list_filter = ()  # Contain only fields in your `custom-user-model` intended for filtering. Do not include `groups`since you do not have it
    search_fields = ()  # Contain only fields in your `custom-user-model` intended for searching
    ordering = ()  # Contain only fields in your `custom-user-model` intended to ordering
    filter_horizontal = () # Leave it empty. You have neither `groups` or `user_permissions`
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('mobile',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(UserModel, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use UserAdmin but you don't have fields which it refers to

- groups
- permissions
- first name
- last name
- username

You should probably need to check UserAdmin class in depth and see what variables you should override

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
    (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
    (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2'),
    }),
)
form = UserChangeForm
add_form = UserCreationForm
change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
ordering = ('username',)
filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

Also errors can give you a hint of where something went wrong